# Issue with downloading pdf and images

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, links

I am facing issues while downloading a cross origin pdf file or image. The file url can be anything. It can be a google drive link , google images or anything . My requirement is that on click of a button I should be able to download the file whatever the link is underneath it. The link is provided by the user in a text box. And also the pdf and images should be downloaded instead of opening it in a browser.

On further research found out the below as reason for this behaviour.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download

Could somebody help me out on this?

Comment: For the PDF it's really simple to deactivate: paste `chrome://settings/content` in the browser > PDF documents and activate the Download PDF option. For images it's strange though, never experienced that.

Comment: About the cross origin thing, I'll let someone else answer that because I'm not familiar with it.